# Is it possible to add an ImageButton to images in a GalleryView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I have a GalleryView which I want to add ImageButton to each image in the gallery.  Is this possible to do since the GalleryView is expecting a touch event?

Comment: [click it](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can catch and ignore the onItemClick from the Gallery object and set an ImageButton to each image (with a custom adapter).

Example:

```
Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx, Tiago. Seems simple enough, which leads me to my next question.  I can start another thread for this question but I thought I'd ask.  So currently i have my gallery layout.xml, in my adapter how do I get the image button to overlay the image? I know I can programmatically add elements to the UI I just havent seen any examples of an image getting overlayed with another image. Thanx